# MariaDB in container overide processor to 60%

Tags: docker, mariadb

I use MariaDB container together to Laravel and Nginx container. But then Laravel in 1 request to the project make few request to the database, MariaDB container set 40-60% to processor on the server. My request make a 7 request to the database and compose the results together. Maybe I must decompose this request to the few smaller and not make 7 requests to the database in 1 request to the server?

Docker-compose settings

```
    db:
      image: mariadb:10.10
      
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MARIADB_DATABASE: beach_db
        MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      
      ports:
        - 8101:3306
      command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I looked logs and docker stats and saw that.

Comment: Are you using an ORM? Try to use a Eager Loading is like Eloquent in Laravel, make use of it to retrieve related data in a single query instead of separate queries for each related model.